# Style appcompat-v7 Toolbar menu background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to styling my appcompat-v7 toolbar to have a different background color for my overflow menu. 
I tried to use the themes for my app and styles for my toolbar, but I was not able to achieve it.

This is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                                                                                              
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/AppToolbarTheme"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Here is the style I created:

```
    <style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/cian</item>
    </style>
```

My main theme is extending Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Does anybody knows how can I do that? If is not possible using the styles is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Check this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699482/styling-the-popup-menu-in-android-5-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699482/styling-the-popup-menu-in-android-5-0

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add this to your toolbar element

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.YourPopup"
```

Then in your `styles.xml` define the popup menu style

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourPopup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/mtrl_white_100</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_light_blue_900</item>
</style>
```

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourPopup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/mtrl_white_100</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/mtrl_light_blue_900</item>
</style>
```

Note that you need to use `android:colorBackground` and never `android:background`. The latter would be applied to everything that doesn't have a background (here the menu itself and each menu item), the former applies only to the popup menu.

Update: The same applies to `textColorPrimary` and `textColor`.

- Popup menu item defines `android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"`.
- `android:textColorPrimary` is a *theme* attribute, it's defined on themes.
- `android:textColor` is a *style* attribute, it's defined on widgets.
- If we defined `android:textColor` in a theme, it would be applied to every widget that doesn't define its own `android:textColor`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21) did.

Comment: @Android I made a mistake, thanks for noticing, now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use the `android` namespace when you are using `AppCompat` attributes. Modify your code as follows:

```
<style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
       <item name="textColorSecondary">@color/cian</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this worked for the color of my icons on the toolbar. Thanks!

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorPrimary'.

Comment: @dr4cul4  find like this `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>`

Comment: `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorPrimary` are some of the attributes that *don't* have appcompat counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your toolbar in your activity.xml file:-

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.YourApp"
```

And then in your styles.xml add this:-

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/TextColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```