# Toolbar ShareActionProvider theme is always dark

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar, shareactionprovider, android-appcompat

I'm trying to add share action to my toolbar. Toolbar is supposed to be orange (or transparent like in this case) with white text and icons, so I'm using this view as `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Also, this is how my app theme declaration looks like:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

No matter how I change the style this is what I get:

[image]

How do I convince ShareActionProvider to get `Light` theme?

Comment: I think help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591447/style-appcompat-v7-toolbar-menu-background

Comment: You can try app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" but it will make the up arrow and menu icon dark.

Comment: It will, but also it doesn't change ShareActionProvider theme...

Answer (score 3):

This is what i did and it worked. i wanted a white background in `ShareActionProvider` with it text being black

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/MainTheme"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

My theme

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_white_1000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_black_1000</item>
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupListStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupListStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I ended up using a custom theme for my toolbar (named `AppTheme.Toolbar` with the parent `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`). It just contains the item `android:textColor` set to black. And it works: the Toolbar text ist white and the text for the share applications is black +1

Answer (score 2):

my solution is based on support library v7 , toolBar , ActionBarActivity , Android Studio

1- remove `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`

2- make sure your base theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

3- go to original code of ShareActionProvider by typing "ShareActionProvider" anywhere in your code then import the v7 one then aim your mouse on it then (ctrl + left click)

4- copy the code in it and paste it in a new java file in you project directory

5- go to your own ShareActionProvider and remove this import if you have it `import android.support.v7.appcompat.R`

6- provide your own share icon because the default one is black
 `Drawable myDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_share);
activityChooserView.setExpandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable(myDrawable);`

7- go to your activity and remove the import you made in step 3 ( to use your own file )

8- go to your onCreateOptionsMenu it should be like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(MainActivity.this);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item , mShareActionProvider);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    return true;
}
```

9- the last step is don't forget to edit your menu.xml

```
app:actionProviderClass=
            "com.yourPackageName.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Comment: This can't work. the class is dependent on some other classes in android which are not public